# Can I reverse my attempt on installing wsl2 on windows 10 build 19044

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, wsl2

My machine is windows 10 build 19044. I attempted to install wsl2 but I closed powershell because I lost my internet connection. Here's what happened. I do have the 4 `Hyper-V`s enabled on `msinfo32`.

Tutorial I followed is [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-on-wsl-2-is-generally-available)

Opened powershell as admin.
I run

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart
```

This has finished without problems.

Then

```
wsl.exe --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

This doesn't work for me so I decided to install:

```
wsl.exe --install
```

I lost my internet connection and nothing is showing on powershell, except the previous commands entered. So I decided to close it. The next time I opened windows, it is slower. And now the 4 `Hyper-V`s on `msinfo32` is all **gone**. **Can I reverse what happened?** I want to install wsl2 from the beginning. Or is there a better way to install wsl2 from this point?

Comment: If you have enabled System Restore, the simplest might be to rollback to before this was done.

Comment: @harrymc I have no idea what that is.

Comment: See for example [How to Do a System Restore of Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc are the files on my hard drive safe? I don't to lose all of this.

Comment: Read the link as to what this does (if enabled and if you have a recent enough snapshot).

Comment: @tenshi Your documents and data *should* be safe during a System Restore.  However, unfortunately it appears that your system is in an unstable state from the mid-upgrade reboot.  I'd recommend backing up critical existing files/data regardless.  Then you'll be prepared if you need to take more drastic action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow these steps

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual

Carefully reading the paragraphs not only executing the commands. You must restart the PC   at some point.

Despite it says about the Windows builds, these instructions work in every supported version of Windows 10 & 11.